# bootstrap dropdown menu to open onclickof button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[please refer the link](http://plnkr.co/edit/6dY0qzlsXT9m2bsLhXp3?p=preview)

Required functionality--Intially dropdown is in disabled state.when i check the checkbox dropdown must open and behave in normal way. i just added this line`$('.btn').removeClass('disabled');`

Comment: Link is broken , kindly update..

Comment: please check the link------->http://plnkr.co/edit/1835M7gxU3tYVpEEheXf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following sample will help you.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#buttonId").click(function(event) {
    $("#dropdownId").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#dropdownId").attr('size',6);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" id="buttonId" value="Click me to enable dropdown">
<br>
<br>
<select id="dropdownId" disabled>
  <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
  <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
  <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

Updated the src as required

Comment: The drop down must open your are just removing the class dropdown.

Comment: just updated the src as u have asked for. See if that helps you

Comment: please check the list u can understand--->http://plnkr.co/edit/1835M7gxU3tYVpEEheXf?p=preview